# xdebug in a "php -a" interactive shell

Tags: php, linux, debugging, xdebug

I CAN do `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=chrebugx"` and run `php test.php` with `xdebug_break()` breakpoints.

However,

```
php -a
include 'test.php'; //includes xdebug_break() statements;
```

runs without stopping, ignoring `xdebug_break()` breakpoints.

Does anyone know how to run "php -a" interactively, while still supporting xdebug_break() points?

EDIT:
I've submitted a bug about this in Xdebug's tracker.
https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1269

Comment: fwiw, if no-one here knows the answer, go bug the developer directly :)

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be easier for you to use it in combination with `-d` [option](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.options.php) and tell xdebug to be [always enabled by default](https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings).

Btw, try dumping `$_ENV` and see whether `XDEBUG_CONFIG` was really passed to PHP.

Comment: var_dump($_ENV); returns an empty array. even after passing `php -d xdebug.profiler_enable=On -a` seems like interactive mode is quite basic. I'm giving psysh a try.

Comment: Found part of the issue, my variables_order was GPCS, not EGPCS. Now I can see that `'XDEBUG_CONFIG' =>string(11) "idekey=atom"` when running mycode with `php code.php` but `php -a; include 'code.php';` will return an $_ENV that's missing XDEBUG_CONFIG. I'll keep looking.

Comment: Manually injecting the XDEBUG_CONFIG env var makes xdebug break when I type exit into the php interactive shell. Specifically, it breaks in an Autoload.php destroy method, I have break on first line enabled. However it doesn't seem to break under any other conditions, which makes it kinda useless.

Comment: Have you tried also running: `export XDEBUG_CONFIG="idekey=chrebugx" && ./phpunit test.php`?

Comment: running code from a file works perfectly, as long as you're not running it from the interactive shell. I've submitted a bug about it. https://bugs.xdebug.org/view.php?id=1269